# What should the customize tag be used for?

Tags: discussion, tags

The current definition of the `customize` tag is:

[Use this tag for questions about modifying a particular action or task within Emacs.](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customize)

This could probably apply to 90% of the questions on the site. Should this be more narrowly defined to refer to the customization interface?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it should apply *only* to Emacs's [customization](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html) interface.  The interface's prefix is even `customize-*`.